# Image is not loading from absolute URL after uploading files on github

Tags: html

Github Repo link: https://github.com/junaidshaikh-js/dog-app

```
<div class="doggos">
    <img
      src="http://placecorgi.com/260/180"
      alt="doggo"
      class="dog-img show"
    />
    <div class="spinner">&#128054;</div>
  </div>
```

After deploying using Github pages the image is not getting updated.

live site link: https://junaidshaikh-js.github.io/dog-app/

But it's working when I checked with a live server in VS code.

What should be the issue?

Comment: You need to use `https` protocol for the images when page is on https

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Open your browser dev tools network tab and see what is happening to those requests

Comment: the console says - net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Comment: sounds wierd. try another image source

Comment: Yeah, I did. Thank you.